# Why $\frac{1}{E-H_0+i\eta}|n\rangle \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{E-E_n+i\eta}|n\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, schroedinger-equation, quantum-states

A Hamiltonian $H_0$ is diagonalized in $\{|n\rangle\}$ i.e. $H_0|n\rangle=E_n|n\rangle$. Why can we write
$$\frac{1}{E-H_0+i\eta}|n\rangle \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{E-E_n+i\eta}|n\rangle$$
$H_0$ is in denominator, how come we can apply $H_0$ directly on $|n\rangle$? Are there any situations where this is not true?

---

**The actual problem I am struggling with (It would be great if anybody can give me some direction to proceed):** I have a Bogoliubov (4-by-4) Hamiltonian $H_B$ which is diagonalized by an anti-unitary matrix $T$ i.e. $T^+\sigma T=\sigma$ where $\sigma=diag(1,1,-1,-1)$. And $T^+H_BT=E_k$ where $E_k$ is diagonal matrix with eigenvalues of $H_B$. Due to Bogoliubov form $H_B$ obey $H_B|T_n\rangle = (\sigma_{nn}E_{nn})\sigma|T_n\rangle$. I wonder if I can write expression
$$
\frac{1}{E-H_B+i\eta}|T_n\rangle \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{1}{E-\sigma_{nn}E_{nn}+i\eta}\sigma|T_n\rangle
$$

Answer (score 1):

The denominator is nowhere zero due to the imaginary $i\eta$ term, so the Taylor series in $H_ß$ and $E_n$ converge everywhere. So you can express the terms as power series where it is clear that each summand of the form $c_k H_0^k|n\rangle$ is equal to the corresponding summand $c_k E_n^k|n\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see weird manipulations of operators, like $\sqrt{\mathcal{O}}$,  $\frac{1}{\mathcal{O}}$, or $\log{\mathcal{O}}$, they are always defined by just doing those operations to the eigenvalues. Now, if the operators aren't diagonalizable in an eigenbasis, then it is more complicated to define these operations, if they can be defined at all.

Let me just say that in the case of inverses, though, you're literally just inverting the matrix. So $\frac{1}{H - E I} = (H - E I)^{-1}$.